# ASP.NET Core Singleton Service created multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am working an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project where I need to register and then use a singleton service inside of Startup.ConfigureServices.

I have the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //....
    //....

    services.AddSingleton<IMyService,MyService>();

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var myService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(myService.DBConnectionString));
}
```

The above code works fine for me to be able to use "MyService" inside ConfigureServices. However later in my application when I try and use MyService the constructor of MyService is being called again. Why is it not using the instance that was already created since I registered the class using `AddSingleton`?

EDIT: I decided to edit to add my end objective to see if maybe there is a different way to get it done. My singleton service provides access to a few settings that could come from 2 different places. One of those settings is a DB connection string. I need that connection string in ConfigureServices so I have it when I call `services.AddDbContext`. I also want to do some logging in the service that gets configuration settings which means I need to get the ILoggerFactory as well.

Comment: Because they are being called from two different service providers. The one you built manually in the configure services method and the one build by the framework after that method went out of scope.

Comment: in earlier versions you could have just returned the provider you built from  configure services but I am not sure if that was changed in more recent versions of asp.net core.

Comment: @Nkosi I added an edit to my original post to indicate what I'm trying to do. Maybe there is a different way to do it?

Comment: @Nkosi I haven't really tried anything else since i'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: Where is your service getting the connection string from?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi the service is getting the connection string (and a few other values) from either the appSettings.json if it's there or by making an external API call using the AWS SDK to pull from the AWS Secrets Manager. That same service is also providing a few other values (also pulled from either AWS or the appSettings.json) but those other values aren't needed in ConfigureServices.

Comment: will the connection string come from multiple places or just settings file? if just from settings file then no need for your service. get it directly from IConfiguration and use it in configure services

Comment: @Nkosi the connection string could come from AWS Secrets Manager

Comment: Then I think that is the actual question you should be asking.

Comment: @Nkosi but I can already do that. Getting the DB connection string from either AWS Secret Manager or the appSettings.json already works. The problem is that I need the service that does that to already be registered (without getting created again later) so I can use that value (from where ever it came) to register my DBContext. See the added line in the code snippet of my original post. `options.UseMySql(myService.DBConnectionString)`. The DBConnectionString property on MyService will return the correct DB connection string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `BuildServiceProvider` from `ConfigureServices` will result in an additional copy of singleton services being created.

Use another approach that defers the access to the service provider in this particular case. `AddDbContext` has an overload that allows for such a case, where the service provider is provided as part of the options action delegate.

```
//...

services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();

services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
    options.UseMySql(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>().DBConnectionString)
);

//....
```

Reference [`AddDbContext<TContext>(IServiceCollection, Action<IServiceProvider,DbContextOptionsBuilder>, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_)

Answer (score 0):

`AddSingleton` tells Unity to construct it once. That "once" is in addition to any constructors that you invoke directly in your code.

If you want to re-use the instance you created, use `AddInstance` instead.

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var myService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();

services.AddInstance<IMyService>(myService);

services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(myService.DBConnectionString));
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the instance from the `serviceProvider` before adding the `IMyService` to the `services`?