# .NET How to access TOptions during startup (Options Pattern)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I am using the [.NET Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to manage my configuration.

This configuration is needed in Controllers (easy with Dependency Injection) but also to configure other services during application startup.

I would have thought that the generic `Services.Configure<MyOptionsClass>` method would return an instance of MyOptionsClass but unfortunately it returns an IServiceCollection?

Is there a clean way to access a bound instance of MyOptionsClass here during startup?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Setup MyOptionsClass for DI
var unwantedServiceCollection = builder.Services.Configure<MyOptionsClass>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(MyOptionsClass.ConfigName));

// Already need to be able to access MyOptionsClass here:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => { options.Authority = instanceOfMyOptionsClass.Authority; });
```

Comment: Found solution here which is ALMOST there, but the solution is not longer using TOptions in DI
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47037031/8250558

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar need in the past and this is what I did:

```
var configOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection(MyOptionsClass.ConfigName);

//You can also add data annotations to your config validate it on start
builder.Services
            .AddOptions<MyOptionsClass>()
            .Bind(configOptions)
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();

var configInstance = configOptions.Get<MyOptionsClass>();
```

Alternatively, you can use [ServiceProviderServiceExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) `GetService<>` or `GetRequiredService<>` to get the service you need by its type. Also, please be wary of using BuildServiceProvider which may create duplicate services as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781807/asp-net-core-singleton-service-created-multiple-times).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Point for `var configInstance = configOptions.Get<MyOptionsClass>();`